# Laravel 8 getting ReflectionException error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

in `Laravel 7` which i installed and i used `nWdart` module, i didn't have any problem. now after migrating project to `Laravel 8` i have some issue which one of them is i get `ReflectionException` error

when i try to running `php artisan route:list` i get below error:

```
  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
      ReflectionException::
        ("Class Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController does not exist")
```

`php artisan module:list` command output:

```
+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+
| Name        | Status  | Order | Path                                   |
+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+
| Blog        | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Blog        |
| Media       | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Media       |
| Profile     | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Profile     |
| Radio       | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Radio       |
| Store       | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Store       |
| Ticket      | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/Ticket      |
| UserMessage | Enabled |       | C:\xampp\htdocs\v8\Modules/UserMessage |
+-------------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+
```

and my routes:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController;

Route::prefix('panel')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('media')->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('mediaResource')->group(function () {
            Route::resource('imagesController', ImagesController::class);
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

`ImagesController` class:

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\Media\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    }

    //...

    public function destroy($id)
    {
    }
}
```

```
 | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController                 | imagesController.store     | 
 Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@store                | web        |
| | GET|HEAD  | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController     | imagesController.index    | 
Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@index  | web |
| | GET|HEAD  | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController/create     | imagesController.create   | 
Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@create | web |
| | DELETE    | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController/{imagesController}| imagesController.destroy  | 
Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@destroy| web |
| | PUT|PATCH | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController/{imagesController}| imagesController.update   | 
Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@update | web |
| | GET|HEAD  | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController/{imagesController}| imagesController.show     | 
Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController@show   | web |
| | GET|HEAD  | panel/media/mediaResource/imagesController/{imagesController}/edit   | imagesController.edit
```

Comment: `Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController` That's a crazy namespace... I've seen Laravel double-up on it before, but never triple... Does it work if you do `use \Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController;`? Sidenote; best to list the package you're using: https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules. It says it's compatible with Laravel 8

Comment: @TimLewis it works when i clicking on class name with `ctrl`

Comment: That just means your IDE can find it. I'll ask again, does it work with `use 
 \Modules\Media\Http\Controllers\ImagesController;`?

Comment: @TimLewis it doesn't work in `routes`, but it work an another classes

Comment: Well that's bizarre... I wouldn't expect the Routes namespacing to be that much different from others, but I haven't worked in Laravel 8 yet. I see that you've opened an issue on the GitHub page, see if that gets anything

Comment: @TimLewis Much more than this problem, none existing route after deleting work fine lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223176/discussion-between-doldurma-and-tim-lewis).